# Spring 3 ,with Java based configuration, and Resources access issue

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-3

I am using Spring 3 ,java based configuration, with BootStrap.

I have downloaded the bootstrap and put the css and js  under resources directory.

The issue that I cann't use these .css from within the freemarker page.
Howeve that I imported them.
As I am using the java based configuration,I have added the "addResourceHandler" as follows:

WebAppConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.springway")
public class WebConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext root = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        root.setServletContext(servletContext);
        root.scan("com.springway");
        root.refresh();

        final ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("spring", new DispatcherServlet(root));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/*");
    }

    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
```

> Tomcat log says :
>
> "WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>
> > [/springway/resources/css/bootstrap-responsive.css] in
> >     DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Directory :

```
-SpringWay
>       -src
>            - main
>                   -webapp
>                           -resources
                            -WEB-INF
                                 -welcome.ftl
                                 -springway.ftl
```

welcome.ftl:

```
[#ftl /]
[#include "springway.ftl" /]


<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li>
    <a href="[@spring.url '/test'/]">Test</a> <span class="divider">/</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Library</a> <span class="divider">/</span>
  </li>
  <li class="active">Data</li>
</ul>
```

springway.ftl:

```
    [#ftl/]
    [#import "spring.ftl" as spring /]

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

        <title>

        </title>

       <link href="[@spring.url '/resources/css/bootstrap-responsive.css'/]" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <link href="[@spring.url '/resources/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css'/]" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <link href="[@spring.url '/resources/css/bootstrap.css'/]" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <link href="[@spring.url '/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css'/]" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

        <script src="[@spring.url '/resources/js/bootstrap.js'/]" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="[@spring.url '/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js'/]" type="text/javascript"></script>
      </head>

    <body ></body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have defined wrong resourceLocation.

Instead of

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
```

you should have done

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/**");
```

Because your css folder is inside resources folder you need to put the extra ** after the / only after that it will identify the css folder otherwise it will load only from the resources folders no subfolders will be considered.

Hope it helped you.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Japan for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spring Security, you might consider adding the webjars to the list of authorized requests by adding this line of code to your SecurityConfiguration Class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
  .authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll()
  **.antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll()**
  .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
 .formLogin().loginPage("/signin").permitAll()
    .and()
//...
 .logout().permitAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Security, you might consider adding the webjars to the list of authorized requests by adding this line of code to your SecurityConfiguration Class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http
   .authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll()
    **.antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll()**
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("/signin").permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout().permitAll();
}
```