# Where did ResourceConfigurer in Spring 3.2.0.RELEASE go?

Tags: spring-mvc

I read in a blog post titled [SPRING 3.1 M2: SPRING MVC ENHANCEMENTS](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/06/13/spring-3-1-m2-spring-mvc-enhancements-2/) that it was possible to replace the `<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />` element with the following equivalent:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

     @Override
     public void configureResourceHandling(ResourceConfigurer configurer) {
         configurer.addPathMapping("/resources/**").addResourceLocation("/resources/");
     }
}
```

However in Spring 3.2.0.RELEASE I don't seem to be able to find `ResourceConfigurer`. Did this functionality make it to an official release ever? It's possible I have something wrong with my dependencies but before I post all of that I just wanted to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This mechanism was re-worked for 3.2, I had the same problem a couple of months ago. Now what you have to do is override a different method. The following seemed to work for me, although you may need to play with the paths etc:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
         registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/").addResourceLocations("/resources/**");
    }
}
```

Comment: The accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939896/spring-3-with-java-based-configuration-and-resources-access-issue) may also help to get the paths correct.